# How to insert data into Microsoft Sql using powershell?

Tags: powershell

**Usecase:**

We need to read the data from the CSV and insert data into SQL. And from SQL we would need to display it in the Sharepoint or PowerBI.

**Solution:**

We have used the SQLCmd from PowerShell to insert the data into the table which is hosted in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Invoke-SQLcmd query can be executed from PowerShell. Below is the sample code.

```
$services=Get-Service 
foreach($service in $services) 
{ 
$ser=$service.Status 
$name=$service.name 
$disname=$service.DisplayName 

$insertquery=" 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceTable] 
           ([Status] 
           ,[Name] 
           ,[DisplayName]) 
     VALUES 
           ('$ser' 
           ,'$name' 
           ,'$disname') 
GO 
" 

Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'testdb.database.windows.net' -query $insertquery -U testuser -P Admin@123 -Database Testdb 

}
```